# Read after Read Dependency in LLVM Memory Dependence Analysis

Tags: c, dependencies, llvm, compiler-optimization

In the figure below, on the left you can see the C code while the part on the right shows the unoptimized LLVM IR form of it.

[The Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOoRa.png)

Running MemoryDependenceAnalysis on the IR finds the memory dependencies. One dependency is shown in both the original code and its IR equivalent using the arrow line.

Here is the output of the analysis which includes the mentioned dependency:

```
Printing analysis 'Print MemDeps of function' for function 'main':
    Def from:   %retval = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %retval, align 4

    Def from:   %d = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %d, align 4

    Def from:   %a = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %a, align 4

    Def from:   store i32 0, i32* %a, align 4
  %0 = load i32, i32* %a, align 4

    Def from:   %b = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 %0, i32* %b, align 4

    Def from:   %0 = load i32, i32* %a, align 4
  %1 = load i32, i32* %a, align 4

    Def from:   store i32 0, i32* %d, align 4
  %2 = load i32, i32* %d, align 4

    Def from:   %c = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 %add, i32* %c, align 4

    Def from:   %2 = load i32, i32* %d, align 4
  store i32 2, i32* %d, align 4
```

In the output from the analysis, we have:

```
Def from:   %0 = load i32, i32* %a, align 4
  %1 = load i32, i32* %a, align 4
```

The variable `a` is read in both statements which is a RAR dependency. As is shown in the code snippet (LLVM-3.9.0 at lib/Analysis/MemoryDependenceAnalysis.cpp:549-551) LLVM considers these loads as defs of each other. What does that mean?

```
    // Must aliased loads are defs of each other.
    if (R == MustAlias)
      return MemDepResult::getDef(Inst);
```

Also, note that the analysis is performed on the IR, not on the C source.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used LLVM but based on your provided C code and LLVM IR, the `a` variable is read 2 times. I don't see any mistake. May I'm wrong?

[image]